# Tenure of data available through Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

What is the maximum duration for which data for a user will be available using Microsoft Graph API? Is this endpoint specific?

Comment: Do you mean after deleting the user? The data stays as long as the objects exist.

Comment: I don't mean deleted users. For an existing user, will I be able to get his data(for example his calendar events) for the whole duration for which he has been using Office365?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.